# Unable to add image to userform

Tags: excel, image, userform

Not sure if anyone else has had this issue, but I've googled several pages and found nothing.
I'm unable to add an image, either in its own frame or to a command button.

I click on the 3 dots against "Picture (None)" and nothing happens, apart from "Picture" greying and the cursor starts flashing to the left of "(None)".

I've tried the same on blank workbooks.
I've tested it on the shared drive where the workbook currently resides, and on my personal C:.
But it all just does the same. -No file select window.

Is this a settings thing I'm not aware of or is it a new office reinstall?
As ever, any help gratefully received.

[image: Userform:Add Image]

Comment: Just tried a full reinstallation of 365 and the issue remains 